# Why isn't the Javascript fontcolor method working for me?

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the text below the title of my countdown timer isn't changing color to red. For some reason, whenever I call the fontcolor() method on a string variable, it ignores the method call and prints out its default font color. How do I fix this?

```html
<body>

<div id="worked"></div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span></h1>
<h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</h1>

</body>

<script>
var handler = function() {
  if (--sec < 0) {
    sec = 59;
    if (--min < 0) {
      min = 0;
      sec = 0;
    }
  }
  var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
  var min2 = min + "m";
  var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
  var sec2 = sec + "s";
var col = ":";
min1.fontcolor("red");
min2.fontcolor("red");
sec1.fontcolor("red");
sec2.fontcolor("red");
col.fontcolor("red");
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1 : min2) + col + (sec < 10 ? sec1 : sec2);
};
var sec = 0;
var min = 15;
handler();
setInterval(handler, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the returned value of `fontcolor()`

`fontcolor()` returns a string embedded in the `<font>` tag

```html
<body>

  <div id="worked"></div>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span></h1>
  <h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</h1>

</body>

<script>
  var handler = function() {
    if (--sec < 0) {
      sec = 59;
      if (--min < 0) {
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
      }
    }
    var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
    var min2 = min + "m";
    var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
    var sec2 = sec + "s";
    var col = ":";
    min1 = min1.fontcolor("red");
    min2 = min2.fontcolor("red");
    sec1 = sec1.fontcolor("red");
    sec2 = sec2.fontcolor("red");
    col = col.fontcolor("red");
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1 : min2) + col + (sec < 10 ? sec1 : sec2);
  };
  var sec = 0;
  var min = 15;
  handler();
  setInterval(handler, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply fontcolor only when updating it to HTML, or save the result as suggested by @Weedoze.

`col.fontcolor("red")` doens't update `col` but returns a new string with the value of `col` wrapped in `<font>`. The values returned so was not saved or used in your code.

```
var col = ":".fontcolor("red");
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1.fontcolor("red") : min2.fontcolor("red")) + col + (sec < 10 ? sec1.fontcolor("red") : sec2.fontcolor("red"));
```

---

```js
var handler = function() {
  if (--sec < 0) {
    sec = 59;
    if (--min < 0) {
      min = 0;
      sec = 0;
    }
  }
  var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
  var min2 = min + "m";
  var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
  var sec2 = sec + "s";
  var col = ":".fontcolor("red");

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1.fontcolor("red") : min2.fontcolor("red")) + col + (sec < 10 ? sec1.fontcolor("red") : sec2.fontcolor("red"));
};
var sec = 0;
var min = 15;
handler();
setInterval(handler, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="worked"></div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span></h1>
<h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</h1>
```